# How to merge two disjointed branches in PlantUML activity diagram with new syntax?

Tags: uml, plantuml, activity-diagram

I want to create an Activity Diagram with PlantUML's [new beta syntax](https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta).

I've got the basic decision logic diagram, but I'm having trouble trying to add a merge node to merge two execution branches. I want branches `A1+` and `B1+` to lead to a common activity and then end. Unfortunately I only got to the point of having two different activities with the same name.

### Current diagram:

```
@startuml
'https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta
start
:Some Start Activity;
if (Decision AB?) then (A)
    if (Decision A1/A2?) then (A1)
        if (Decision4 A1+/A1-?) then (A1+)
            :Activity for A1+;
            :Activity_2 for A1+;
            :Activity_3 for A1+;
            :Activity_4 for A1+;
            :**TODO Common Activity for A1+, B1+**;
            stop
        else (A1-)
            :Activity for A1-;
            stop
        endif
    else (A2)
    endif
else (B)
    if (Decision B1/B2?) then (B1)
        if (Decision B1+/B1-?) then (B1+)
            :**TODO Common Activity for A1+, B1+**;
            stop
        else (B1-)
        endif
    else (B2)
    endif
endif
:Common activity for A2, B2, B1-;
stop

@enduml
```

Render:
[image: RenderOfCurrent]

### Goto/Label workaround attempt

Now, I've tried to solve this with a workaround by using the Goto/Label syntax, but that doesn't really solve the problem. Not only is it ugly, it also breaks the layout, since it draws a line over other elements.
With Goto/Label workaround:

```
@startuml
'https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta
start
:Some Start Activity;
if (Decision AB?) then (A)
    if (Decision A1/A2?) then (A1)
        if (Decision4 A1+/A1-?) then (A1+)
            :Activity for A1+;
            :Activity_2 for A1+;
            :Activity_3 for A1+;
            :Activity_4 for A1+;
            label myLabel
            :**TODO Common Activity for A1+, B1+**;
            stop
        else (A1-)
            :Activity for A1-;
            stop
        endif
    else (A2)
    endif
else (B)
    if (Decision B1/B2?) then (B1)
        if (Decision B1+/B1-?) then (B1+)
            label dummyLabel
            goto myLabel
        else (B1-)
        endif
    else (B2)
    endif
endif
:Common activity for A2, B2, B1-;
stop

@enduml
```

Render:
[image]

How do I force PlantUML to create a simple merge node and join the two execution branches leading to a common Activity for `A1+` and `B1+`?

Comment: Have you found any better solution? I'm facing the same issue and would love to find something better than spanning hidden lables.

Comment: @fjsv no. I am now of the opinion that the new syntax is inherently deeply flawed, and they need to go back to the drawing board. On the meantime, I recommend using the old deprecated syntax.